# how i set up an react-native environment with android studio?

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio

```
<============-> 99% EXECUTING [40s]
> :app:installDebug
```

is that normal behaviour for setting up? I have been installing for more than 10 mins, but still load around 99%, does't move further for a long while, what is the problem with this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: i updated the question, do u know what is the problem?

Comment: What is the payload?

Comment: At times it's cache. 
you need to clean gradle then try again

Answer (score 1):

At times its an issue with cache, you can clear gradle with

```
cd android then ./gradlew clean
```